# Degrees of Freedom in Factorial RCB anova

Tags: anova, modeling, degrees-of-freedom

The degrees of freedom calculated for my problem, and the degrees of freedom in R output are different. This is a Factorial RCB with 3 reps, 7 treatments and 2 levels. Here is my output.

```
                  Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
fRep               2  1391.9   695.9  3.6847  0.043417 *  
Treatment          6  5686.0   947.7  5.0174  0.002759 ** 
Variety            1 12855.7 12855.7 68.0642 7.221e-08 ***
Treatment:Variety  6   959.8   160.0  0.8469  0.549161    
Residuals         20  3777.5   188.9
```

However, when I calculate my expected degrees of freedom I get the following values: fRep = (3-1) = 2; Treatment = (7-1) = 6; Variety = (2-1) = 1, TxV = (7-1)(2-1) = 6; [those were all good...here's the issue] Residuals = (3-1)(7*2-1) = 26 NOT 20 like the output says. Also, the total d.o.f. should be 7*3*2-1 = 41, but the total from the output is 2+6+1+6+20 = 35.

Any ideas on how to resolve this are appreciated.

[Data set used for this analysis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8akPwZEbh0zbXJoQ091dVlWVVU/view?usp=sharing)